# c# refactoring - How is it done? CodeDom, EnvDTE, another way?

Tags: c#, code-generation

What method does VS use to manipulate the cs file when refactoring. I.e if you extract a method.

I am 100% sure (I hope) it is not T4, It could be EnvDTE or CodeDom but could not find out which one and was hoping someone knew. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Automation Object Model is what I was after:

["Automation Object Model - MSDN"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za2b25t3%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Simple refactoring is done with snippets:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring

Comment: Thank you for the reply, my next question would be, if a snippet declaratively describes how the code should be manipulated, which class or method parses the snippet to do the work.